# How to make a getter function to change a value in the object itself?

Tags: c++

How can I make a `get()` function to change values inside my class?

For example :

```
class A
{
private:
   int a;
   int b;

public:
   int func()
  {
      return a; 
  }
};

main()
{
   A the_Class = A();
   int c = the_Class.func();
   int g = 5;
   A.func() = g;
}
```

`func()` is a normal getter function. But I want it to be able to change the value of `a` in `the_Class` to the value of `g`.

Comment: Return a reference rather than a value. `int & func()`.

Comment: Not sure *why* you would want to do this, but returning a *reference* to the `a` member would possibly do what you want.

Comment: Return a reference. Also, `func` is not static so you can't call it the way your code suggests.

Comment: Tactical note: Think hard before naming a function "get" and allowing it to both get and set.

Comment: Returning a non-const reference is generally considered a bad idea, as it breaks encapsulation. What is wrong with `A.func( g )` and `void A::func( int x ) { a = x; }` (a setter function)?

Comment: Tactical note: having a `public` function that allows unfettered read and write access to a `private` variable essentially renders the variable `public`. Gives you a good place to hang a debugger breakpoint, though, something you don't usually get from a `public` variable.

Answer (score 0):

To use a function for both getter and setter you can create either two functions with different parameters. One if you just want to return the value **a** and another function with the same name but with parameters, this time you set value and return the value **a**.

see the below code.

```
public:
       int func()
      {
          return a; 
      }

      // get and set func

      int func(int value){
          a=value;
          return a;
      }
 

main(){

    A the_Class = A();
    
// normal get
       int c = the_Class.func();

       int g = 5;

// set and get
       int d=the_Class.func(g);

    }
```

Comment: While this is undoubtedly a better design, it doesn't actually answer the OP's question, as it was asked. I'm inclined to downvote your answer (which I haven't done yet), unless you update it to answer the actual question (how can a function be used as both a getter and a setter).